# I would like to get more than 5 results of activities with the youtube API v3

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I have an issue when I try to get the activities using the youtube API V3

I have this:

> 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activitiespart=snippet,contentDetails&channelId='+channelId+'&key='+APIKey;

The problem is that it is only displaying 5 values, I would like to know where I should put the maxResults=50 in this line because it is no displaying anything

Answer (score 1):

Just tack it on the end its just another parameter in the HTTP Get request.

> 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activitiespart=snippet,contentDetails&channelId='+channelId+'&key='+APIKey&maxResults=50;

Answer (score 0):

Valid request:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=contentDetails,snippet&channelId='.$channelId.'&key='.$apiKey.'&maxResults=50